# Could i use Adaboost to solve the linear regression problem？

Tags: machine-learning

Two months ago，i have learn the adaboost and I am surprised at it strength，so i have a question，could it can be used to solve the relationship between Tea polyphenols and spectrum? In many papers they use linear regression to predict tea polyphenols through spectral data.So can i use adaboost to solve this problem？
（I hope I made it clear）

Comment: You can use ```adaboostreggresor``` to solve your regression problems. For two machine learning tasks that is ```Classification``` and ```Regression``` ,there is ```adaboostclassifier``` and for regression there is ```adaboostregresor```. This link can help you how to implement it https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html

Answer (score 1):

*@think_maths already gave you a working practical solution, so let me give you a bit of intuition*

[image: Adaboost Algorithm]

If you look at the algorithm, It's pretty simple. The job of Adaboost is to give proper weights to the observations and classifiers/regressors so that the predictions for unusual observations become better. In the picture, function G(x) is any machine learning model of your choice, It could be `Linear Regression` as well.
You could read some paper if you want to learn deeper about it -
[AdaBoost.RT: A boosting algorithm for regression problems](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4116773_AdaBoostRT_A_boosting_algorithm_for_regression_problems).

also this thread -
[Can AdaBoost be used for regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395978/can-adaboost-be-used-for-regression)